# How to connect to a bluetooth device with android smartphone using only its Mac adress?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mac-address

I'm making an android app that is supposed to send values of three
 seekbars through bluetooth but I don't know how to programmatically connect it 
 to a paired bluetooth device by clicking on its name on the list that shows the paired devices
 Any help would be much appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private SeekBar redcontrol = null;
private SeekBar greencontrol = null;
private SeekBar bluecontrol = null;
private TextView redv;
private TextView greenv;
private TextView bluev;
private ListView lv;
public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

LinearLayout linearLayout;
Button on, off, button;
private static final UUID MY_UUID =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        // Insert bluetooth devices MAC address
private static String address = "00:14:02:13:08:21";
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

    finish();
        System.exit(10);
    }
}



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btadapter = (BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());



    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    redv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redv);
    greenv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greenv);
    bluev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bluev);
    redcontrol = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    greencontrol = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    bluecontrol = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    redcontrol.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChanged = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChanged = progress;
            redv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    greencontrol.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChanged = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChanged = progress;
            greenv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,

           //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    bluecontrol.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChanged = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChanged = progress;
            bluev.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,
               //     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on);
    off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);

    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            on.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#57D3E8"));
            off.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EAEAEA"));
            if (!btadapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Turning On"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already On",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            off.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#57D3E8"));
            on.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EAEAEA"));
            if (btadapter.isEnabled()) {
                btadapter.disable();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Off"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}
public void list(View view){
    pairedDevices = btadapter.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        list.add(bt.getName()  +"\n" + bt.getAddress()  );


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                if ("00:14:02:13:08:21".equals(device.getAddress())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "That's the right one ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }


            }

            view.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

}


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="460dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:id="@+id/id"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.arduinolight.app.MainActivity"
android:background="#9DC42C"
>




<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="750dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >



<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="310dp"
android:layout_height="800dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<Button
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Paired Devices"
android:onClick="list"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
android:id="@+id/button" />
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="RED Light"
        android:id="@+id/redlight"
        android:textColor="#59126F"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/greenlight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="GREEN Light"
        android:id="@+id/greenlight"
        android:textColor="#59126F"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="134dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bluelight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/greenlight"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="BLUE Light"
        android:id="@+id/bluelight"
        android:textColor="#59126F"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Red :"
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#F51E3E"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/on"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Green :"
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:textColor="#59126F"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redlight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="  0"
        android:id="@+id/redv"
        android:textColor="#F51E3E"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/red"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="  0"
        android:id="@+id/greenv"
        android:textColor="#04670F"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/green"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/green" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Blue :"
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:textColor="#292EFF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/greenv"
        android:layout_marginLeft="205dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="  0"
        android:id="@+id/bluev"
        android:textColor="#1850C6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bluetooth :"
        android:textColor="#59126F"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/on"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:background="#EAEAEA" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/off"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/on"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#EAEAEA" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arduinolightning.app"
 >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Arduino Lighting"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.arduinolightning.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="Arduino Lighting" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```